# R: Force a subset of a data frame to remain as a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, it seems that if I were to create a subset of a data frame with 1 column, it becomes a vector instead.

```
input <- structure(list(X2 = 0, X1 = 1L), .Names = c("X2", "X1"), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")
input
#   X2 X1
# 1  0  1
input <- input[,input[1,]>=1]
input
# [1] 1
as.data.frame(input)
#   input
# 1     1
```

When I use `as.data.frame(input)`, I lose the column name of the vector. Because I do not know the name of "X1", I cannot do something like `names(as.data.frame(input)) <- "X1"`. Is there any way to force R to keep the data frame format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `drop` argument in `[`:

```
> input[,input[1,]>=1, drop=F]
  X1
1  1
```